# Select bar color in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

In IntelliJ IDEA, what is the color of the bar for the current highlighted select row (blue bar in the popup below) called?  I want to adjust the bar color but cannot find it under "Preferences > Editor > Color Scheme".

[image: Select bar]

Comment: AFAIK that has to be controlled by the GUI Theme and not color schema (which is Editor area mainly). Try another GUI Theme (they are available as ordinary plugins, e.g. see https://plugins.jetbrains.com/contest/intellij-themes/2019) or create your own / customize existing -- see http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/reference_guide/ui_themes/themes_intro.html

Comment: I did import a new theme and made a copy of it, but the select bar it uses is light gray and very hard to see.  Using "One dark" theme, which is really nice except this one annoying part.  I can go back to Dracula and bar is blue there.  I am not sure where to edit my copy of the custom theme, is that in the install directory of IntelliJ?

Comment: Sometimes some colors do not get updates until IDE restart. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-201293. As to the actual colors (which one to change in particular) -- sorry, no ideas (I may only suggest to check all docs there and see if you can locate color by it's code in existing theme - print screen, into pic editor, look up the color code, search for it in theme file). Check this blog post and link as well: https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2019/03/brighten-up-your-day-add-color-to-intellij-idea/

Comment: Thanks, I found that setting appearance to Dracula and color scheme from the Theme, I was able to get the colors from theme and UI colors fro Dracula.  Not all contained, but at least it works.